# Swift + didUpdateUserLocation not getting called

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, xcode6.0.1, mkuserlocation

I am not able to call `MKMapView` delegate method `didUpdateUserLocation`.

What I did so far:

1. Add framework `MapKit.framwork` in project
2. Import framework in view controller by `import MapKit` line
3. Add key in plist file

   `<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
   <true/>`
4. Code in view controller

Added delegate `didUpdateUserLocation` method to check location is updated or not but never called.

```
// MARK: - MapView delegate methods

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    // Calling...
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didUpdateUserLocation userLocation: MKUserLocation!) {
   // Not getting called
}

// MARK: - View lifeCycle methods   
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    self.mapView.delegate = self
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    self.mapView.pitchEnabled = true
    self.mapView.showsBuildings = true
}
```

I have used simulator and change simulator custom location to check whether it is called or not? The method `regionDidChangeAnimated` is called perfectly!.

The same thing works for iOS7. what additional effort is remains for Swift map location update?

**Edit:** Plist keys

[image]

Also permission alert not prompted.

Comment: The `value` for the key `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` must be a text, namely the question the user gets prompted when the system asks for permission to use the location services.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You have to keep the reference to `CLLocationManager`.
2. You have to wait `locationManager(_:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:)` delegate method called, before `.startUpdatingLocation()` and `showsUserLocation = true`.
3. According to [the document](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW26): `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` value type is String.

Try:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    // MARK: - View lifeCycle methods
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        self.mapView.delegate = self
        self.mapView.pitchEnabled = true
        self.mapView.showsBuildings = true
    }

    // MARK: - LocationManager delegate methods

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        switch status {
        case .Authorized, .AuthorizedWhenInUse:
            manager.startUpdatingLocation()
            self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        default: break
        }
    }

    // MARK: - MapView delegate methods


    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didUpdateUserLocation userLocation: MKUserLocation!) {
        println(userLocation)
        // Not getting called
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes. I have to called first `didChangeAuthorizationStatus`

Answer (score 2):

Besides the other answers I want to summarize here:

You have put the key `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` in your `info.plist`. The `value` for that key must be a **String** containing the text of the question when the user gets prompted by the system to ask for location services permission.

According to the key, you must request the permission by calling

```
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
```

You probably may have answered the question so your answer may be already saved in the user preferences. The best way is to completely deinstall the app from the simulator and reinstall it so you will be asked again.

Comment: And you are right we have to pass string value for key `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`.

Answer (score 1):

For applications that runs on iOS 8, you will need to add two keys in plist file:

> NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription (you already have this one)
>
> NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

Also you will need to wrap up check if app is running under iOS8 and if so add bellow two lines. If it is iOS 7 or under you will need to skip those two lines. If you forget to do this, app will crash on lower versions.

```
// You have this check
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
// Add this one
locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
```

Comment: It is not neccessary to include both keys.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are asking for when in use authorization by

```
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
```

and in pList you are adding `<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>` which is for always authorization . You need to use `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` Key

Comment: Tried same still no luck.

Comment: I do not understand the reason for downvotes here? isnt this a possible reason for the issue ? and one should note that the answer was given before the question was updated

Answer (score 0):

fixed it!

After ios8 MKMapView did not load LocationCoordinate automatically。
If we want to use MKMapView to load the more accurate location with "-mapView:didUpdateUserLocation":

**Premise:**
1.setup the mapView delegate.
2.setShowsUserLocation:YES
3.mapView must in a container(addSubview:mapView)!!!!!

Example:

```
self.mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
_mapView.delegate = self;
[_mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:_mapView];
```

i add MapView to Window because the code in the UtilSingleton, you can add to your controller view generally.

Answer (score 0):

After trying all above answer, if "didUpdateUserLocation" delegate not being called then choose simulator click on Debug from menu bar choose Location then choose Apple. I tried above all answer but location was set to custom, So I change it to Apple and delegate method called. After that i again set it to custom now it is showing location.